# Tarantool cartridge-springdata(spring data for tarantool) does not work when language is kotlin

Tags: kotlin, tarantool, tarantool-cartridge

We want to use tarantool in out project that is based on kotlin language and spring framework so we tried the spring-data project for tarantool which is cartridge-springdata. The example explained in [cartridge-springdata](https://github.com/tarantool/cartridge-springdata) does not work when language is kotlin. The same example works when everything is in Java. The following stack trace is given:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookService' defined in file [C:\Projects\TarantoolTest\build\classes\kotlin\main\ir\ebb\oms\BookService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tarantoolRepositoryOperationsMapping' defined in class path resource [ir/ebb/oms/TarantoolConfig222.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'tarantoolRepositoryOperationsMapping' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tarantoolTemplate' defined in class path resource [ir/ebb/oms/TarantoolConfig222.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'tarantoolTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tarantoolMappingContext' defined in class path resource [ir/ebb/oms/TarantoolConfig222.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at ir.ebb.oms.TarantoolAppKt.main(TarantoolApp.kt:23) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tarantoolRepositoryOperationsMapping' defined in class path resource [ir/ebb/oms/TarantoolConfig222.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'tarantoolRepositoryOperationsMapping' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tarantoolTemplate' defined in class path resource [ir/ebb/oms/TarantoolConfig222.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'tarantoolTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tarantoolMappingContext' defined in class path resource [ir/ebb/oms/TarantoolConfig222.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tarantoolTemplate' defined in class path resource [ir/ebb/oms/TarantoolConfig222.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'tarantoolTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tarantoolMappingContext' defined in class path resource [ir/ebb/oms/TarantoolConfig222.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tarantoolMappingContext' defined in class path resource [ir/ebb/oms/TarantoolConfig222.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer$Discoverers$2.lambda$discover$3(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer$Discoverers$2.discover(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:160) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.discover(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:79) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicPersistentEntity.java:112) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicPersistentEntity.java:93) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
at org.springframework.data.tarantool.core.mapping.BasicTarantoolPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicTarantoolPersistentEntity.java:35) ~[spring-data-tarantool-0.4.0.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.tarantool.core.mapping.TarantoolMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(TarantoolMappingContext.java:35) ~[spring-data-tarantool-0.4.0.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.tarantool.core.mapping.TarantoolMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(TarantoolMappingContext.java:15) ~[spring-data-tarantool-0.4.0.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:367) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:333) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.initialize(AbstractMappingContext.java:462) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractMappingContext.java:454) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tarantoolRepositoryOperationsMapping' defined in class path resource [ir/ebb/oms/TarantoolConfig222.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'tarantoolRepositoryOperationsMapping' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tarantoolTemplate' defined in class path resource [ir/ebb/oms/TarantoolConfig222.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'tarantoolTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tarantoolMappingContext' defined in class path resource [ir/ebb/oms/TarantoolConfig222.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.reflect.full.KClasses
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
... 76 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'tarantoolTemplate' defined in class path resource [ir/ebb/oms/TarantoolConfig222.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'tarantoolTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tarantoolMappingContext' defined in class path resource [ir/ebb/oms/TarantoolConfig222.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tarantoolMappingContext' defined in class path resource [ir/ebb/oms/TarantoolConfig222.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.reflect.full.KClasses
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi Milad, what is the JDK version you are using? It seems that some Kotlin libraries are missing in the runtime. Specify also the Kotlin SDK version, so we'll try to reproduce it.

See also: 
1) https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9984
2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42993#focus=Comments-27-4495943.0-0

Comment: BTW, feel free to create an issue in the [cartridge-springdata](https://github.com/tarantool/cartridge-springdata/issues) repository

Comment: @akudiyar you are right. reflections for kotlin is missing in my case. I explained in answer. I suggest in [cartridge-springdata](https://github.com/tarantool/cartridge-springdata) documentation this kotlin specific problem gets mentioned and explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What [akudiyar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/838231/akudiyar) said is right. kotlin does not include reflection by default. It should be declared as a dependency separately. The problem explained in question has occurred because it needs reflection to do what it needs to do but kotlin reflection is not included in project. So adding kotlin-reflect to project fixed the problem.

gradle:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:yout-kotlin-version"
```